# Как сделать правильное формирование ссылок по скрипту?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

Как сделать, чтобы при алгоритме:

1. клик по чекбоксу из первого блока
2. клик по радио второго блока
3. снова клик по чекбоксу первого блока

не выполнялся переход на сформированную скриптом ссылку, а просто выполнялось обычное выделение второго чекбокса, не забывая "часть 2" скрипта (дословно отмечена в JS-коде)?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
const checks = document.querySelectorAll('input.form-check-input')

checks.forEach(c => c.addEventListener('click', onClick))

function onClick() {
  if ([...checks].filter(c => c.checked).length === 3) {
    const url = 'https://site.ru' + [...checks].filter(c => c.checked).map(c => c.value).join('')

   location.href = url
  }
}
});


// (часть 2) отмена активации предыдущего чекбокса-соседа
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
document.querySelectorAll('.first input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    if (this.checked) {
      var clicked = this;
      this.closest(".first").querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(item => {
        if (item != this)
          item.checked = false;
      });
    }
  });
});
})
```

```css
.first-check {
 background: wheat;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.first {
 background: lightgreen;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 padding: 15px;
}
.second {
 background: lightblue;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 padding: 15px;
}
.smart-2 {
  background: wheat;
 margin-bottom: 12px; 
}
.thrd {
 background: #f0f0f0;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 padding: 15px;
}
.product-container {
    background: wheat;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="first">
  <div class="fix-item first-check">
   <input id="link17" class="linkinp form-check-input" name="link" type="checkbox" value="/remont-materinskoj-platy/">
   <label for="link17 first-check" class="link">Ремонт материнской платы
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="fix-item first-check">
   <input id="link17" class="linkinp form-check-input" name="link" type="checkbox" value="/remont-materinskoj-platy/">
   <label for="link17 first-check" class="link">Ремонт материнской платы
   </label>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="second">
 <div class="fix-item2 smart-2">
  <input id="link01" class="linkinp form-check-input" name="link" type="radio" value="honor/">
  <label for="link01" class="link">Honor</label>
 </div>
 <div class="fix-item2 smart-2">
  <input id="link01" class="linkinp form-check-input" name="link" type="radio" value="honor/">
  <label for="link01" class="link">Honor</label>
 </div>
 </div> 
   <div class="thrd">
 <li class="product-container  width33 floatleft ">
  <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="huawei-gthree" type="checkbox"> Huawei G3 </li>
</div></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

const obj = {
  a: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
  b: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
  c: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
}

inputs.forEach(addListener);

function addListener(input) {
  input.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
}

function onClickHandler(e) {
  changeObjectValues(obj[e.target.name], e.target.value, true);
  const checkedInputs = getСlosestCheckedInputs(e.target);

  if (checkedInputs.length > 0) uncheckInputs(checkedInputs);

  if (isAllChecked()) {
    const url = 'https://site.ru' + Object.keys(obj).map(getPath).join('');
    alert(url);
  }
}

function getPath(key) {
  return obj[key].path;
}

function isAllChecked() {
  return Object.keys(obj).every(isChecked);
}

function isChecked(key) {
  return obj[key].isChecked === true;
}

function changeObjectValues(obj, path, isChecked) {
  obj.path = path;
  obj.isChecked = isChecked;
}

function getСlosestCheckedInputs(target) {
  const inputs = target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  const checkedInputs = [];

  inputs.forEach(function getCheckedInput(input) {
    if (input.checked && input != target) checkedInputs.push(input);
  });

  return checkedInputs;
}

function uncheckInputs(checkedInputs) {
  checkedInputs.forEach(function uncheck(input) {
    input.checked = false;
  })
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.a>.row {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.b>.row {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.c>.row {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<!-- A -->
<div class="a container">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="a-1" type="checkbox" value="/a-1/" name="a">
    <label for="a-1">a 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input id="a-2" type="checkbox" value="/a-2/" name="a">
    <label for="a-2">a 2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- B -->
<div class="b container">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="b-1" type="radio" value="b-1/" name="b">
    <label for="b-1">b 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input id="b-2" type="radio" value="b-2/" name="b">
    <label for="b-2">b 2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- C -->
<div class="c container">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="c-1" type="checkbox" value="c-1" name="c">
    <label for="c-1">c 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input id="c-2" type="checkbox" value="c-2" name="c">
    <label for="c-2">c 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Чем может быть вызвана ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'path' of undefined
    at changeObjectValues (custom.js:270)
    at HTMLInputElement.onClickHandler (custom.js:246)"

Comment: Скорее всего у тебя нету инпута с таким именем, которое есть в объекте.т.е вот эта строка - obj[e.target.name] передаёт undefined в функцию.